# Publish jenkins job result to github pull request

Tags: git, jenkins, github, fusion

I have a requirement.
Problem statement: I have a fusion/jenkins job. Whenever the fusion job is successful, it should publish the result of test cases to github pull request. For example, it should publish the TestNg results to github pull request.

Any pointers would be good.

Answer (score 0):

As a first pointer, you can look at [GitHub API Comments](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/working-with-comments/) which allows you to add a comment to a Pull Request through the [Issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment).

That allows you to publish a block of text, whose content can represent TestNG results (properly formatted).
That workaround allows you to publish anything, considering there is no native TestNG integration in GitHub PR.

That script can easily be added in a post-build step of a Jenkins job, executed if the previous steps succeed.